# DwinsHs for Inno Setup: How to add an apikey HTTP header of a request?

Tags: https, http-headers, inno-setup, pascalscript, dwinshs

I'm using a third party tool by the name of DwinsHs for Inno Setup.

This third party tool provides me the capability for downloading files as part of the installation.

I want to send an HTTPS request to remote server and I would like to pass an `apikey` to the header of the request but it returns error 401.

This is the code:

```
[ISPP]
#define fileURL "https://myserver.xom?apikey=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"

[Code]
Source: "<path_to_my_file>"; \
  DestDir: "{app}"; \
  Flags: external deleteafterinstall; \
  Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('<path_to_my_file>'), '{#fileURL}', 'mySetup', 'Get', 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution;

So, keep the url without `?apkikey=...`

```
[ISPP]
#define fileURL "https://myserver.xom"
```

And adding the `apikey` in the header by editing `const HTTP_HEADER` in `dwinshs.iss`:

```pascal
  HTTP_HEADER = 'apikey: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx';
```