# DwinsHs for Inno Setup: Edit HTTP_HEADER const for URL to download during the install

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript, dwinshs

I posted this question [DwinsHs for Inno Setup: How to add an apikey HTTP header of a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61584074/dwinshs-for-inno-setup-how-to-add-an-apikey-http-header-of-a-request/61587788#61587788)

And now I want to edit the `HTTP_HEADER` during the install. The `HTTP_HEADER` is a `const`. I changed it to a `var` to be able to edit it. But when I do this, during the download I have an error *"failed to send request to the HTTP server"*

In my setup, the user should insert credentials (user, password) in a previous wizard page, and after that the setup get the APIKEY of the user session from the remote server from where it will download the files that the user asked for.

The `HTTP_HEADER` `const` is used by `HttpSendRequest(hRequest, HTTP_HEADER, Length(HTTP_HEADER), '', 0);` in the `dwinshs.iss` :

```pascal
function HttpSendRequest(hRequest: HINTERNET; lpszHeaders: PAnsiChar; dwHeadersLength: DWORD; lpOptional: PAnsiChar;
  dwOptionalLength: DWORD): BOOL;
external 'HttpSendRequestA@wininet.dll stdcall delayload setuponly';
```

I changed the type of `HTTP_HEADER` to `PAnsiChar` but I have the same error.

Can you tell me how to resolve my problem, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `HTTP_HEADER` declaration in `dwinshs.iss` to:

```pascal
var HTTP_HEADER: string;
```

And then modify the value as you need in your code, prior to the file download:

```pascal
HTTP_HEADER := 'Header: value';
```